# (c++)Input needs to be a single character, but it accepts multiple characters and checks the first letter

Tags: c++, input

I'm having a problem with a program I've built.
It should take input from the user and check whether it's 'P' or 'M'.
The problem is that I only want it to work if you enter 'P' or 'M', as it is now it accepts as 'M' anything you type as long as it starts with an 'M' (eg. if you type "morse" it will accept it as 'M').
I'm not a programmer and don't have much knowledge of c++, I just made it for fun. An example of how it is:

```
int main(){
  std::cout << "Enter 'M' or 'P'\n";
  char slction;
Inputrror:
  std::cin >> slction;
  switch (slction) {
  case 'M':
    goto Morse;
    break;
  case 'm':
    goto Morse;
    break;
  case 'P':
    goto Text;
    break;
  case 'p':
    goto Text;
    break;
  default:
    std::cout << "Please only enter 'M' or 'P'\n;
    goto Inputrror;
    break;
  }
Morse:
  std::cout << "Morse\n;"
  return 1;
Text:
  std::cout << "Text\n;"
  return 1;
}
```

EDIT: I tried to read the input as a string like it was suggested and it now works properly. The correct version:

```
int main() {
  std::cout << "Enter 'M' or 'P'\n";
  std::string slction;

Inputrror:
  std::cin >> slction;
  if (slction == "M" || slction == 'm') {
    goto Morse;
  }
  else if (slction == "P" || slction == 'p') {
    goto Text;
  }
  else {
    std::cout << "Please only enter 'P' or 'M'\n";
    goto Inputrror;
  }

Morse:
  std::cout << "Morse\n";
  return 1;

Text:
  std::cout << "Text\n";
  return 1;

}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Unfortunately your question only contains requirements: it is not showing any efforts from your side to solve this problem yourself.  Please [edit] your question to show [your attempt far](http://whathaveyoutried.com), and you'll be much more likely to receive answers that help you progress.  Show us your work so far as a [mcve], the result you were expecting and the results you got, and we'll help you figure it out. It may help to re-read [ask].

Comment: Please show your code, we cannot know what you mean eg with "... it redirects to the first switch case." without the code

Comment: Note that still with the corrected version, the program will accept input like `M garbage`.  If you don't want that to be the case, you could look into using `std::getline` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One comment before I answer:

Instead of

```
case 'M':
  goto Morse;
  break;
case 'm':
  goto Morse;
  break;
```

you could use

```
case 'M':
case 'm':
  goto Morse;
  break;
```

`break` stops the block so as long as you don't use it you can nest one after another. You can even do stuff like:

```
case 'M':
  cout << "CAPITALIZED";
case 'm':
  goto Morse;
  break;
```

Now, to your question: you are reading a `char`, meaning it will only take the first letter you input. Use a string instead if you want to be able to read words too:

```
string slction;
cin >> slction;
```

PD: remember to change the `case 'M'` and other options' quotes to double quotes (for strings)

PD2: you can't use switch with strings, so you will have to use if/else blocks

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I didn't know that I could do that in switch.

Comment: oh, btw, you can't use switch with string, my bad (haven't used c++ in a while), so you will have to use "if/else" blocks

Comment: Yeah I know that, thanks. If you look at the edit in my post I'm having some difficulty with reading the input as a string too, unfortunately.

Comment: It should work with the capitalized versions "P" and "M". The problem is you are using `slction == "M" || 'm'` and that means "is slction equal to M"? and when the program answers it's not, the next question is "m?", and obviously that doesn't make a lot of sense. Try changing it to: `slction == "M" || slction == "m"`

Comment: Well, I had that wrong in my mind for so long, after correcting it like you said it works flawlessly, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

With what was said in the first answer, additionally you could use `#include <cctype>` toupper() function to remove extra cases. As well as validate your input with if statements.

example validation function:

```
char isValid(char &selection){

    std::cin >> selection;
    selection = toupper(selection); // ctype.h for toupper changes all to uppercase characters

    //checks to see if more than 1 character is inputed
    if (std::cin.get() != '\n'){
            std::cin.ignore(256, '\n'); //ignores 256 chars until newline('\n')
            std::cin.clear(); // clears the input
            selection = '\0'; // sets selection to null
    }
    return selection;
}
```

[DEMO](https://ideone.com/ndlASc)